An open set which is not the union of a closed set and a countable set
The following fact is probably a known result:

Fact. Let $X$ be an uncountable Polish space. Then there exists an open subset of $X$ which is not the union of a closed set and a countable set.

Proof: By Cantor–Bendixson theorem, $X$ can be partitioned into $\{X^\star,V\}$, where $X^\star$ is the set of all condensation points and $V:=X\setminus X^\star$ is countable open. Pick $\eta \in X^\star$, which is possible since $X$ is uncountable Polish. We claim that $U:=X\setminus \{\eta\}$ satisfies the claim. Note that $U$ is an uncountable open set and it does not contain $\eta$.
Let us suppose for the sake of contradiction that there are a closed set $F$ and a countable set $C$ such that $U = F\cup C$.
Since $\eta$ is a condensation point of $X$, we can pick $x_n\in B(\eta,2^{-n})\setminus(C\cup\{\eta\})$ for every $n$. Then $x_n \in F$ for each $n$ and $F$ is closed. Hence $\eta\in F\subseteq U$, which is the claimed contradiction.
Do you have a reference for the above result?

Isn't your "sketch" an actual proof? It's hard to find an "official reference" for a three sentence proof. What exactly are you looking for?

Should it be Bendixson? Or is this spelling used, too?

@MartinSleziak, re, I agree, and edited accordingly.

@LSpice Thank you, the correct spelling is Bendixson indeed. I was just asking whether it has been written explicitly somewhere, as a fact or an exercise, since it seems to be a standard result.
